# Annotation stop working after migration from grails 2.5.6 to 3.3

Tags: grails, annotations, spring-annotations

I have implemented some custom annotations. All of them were working before the migration to grails 3, but after we migrate the code, the applications throws nothing, everything is working but the annotations are just been ignored.

This is one of my @annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface UnoMetricsCounter {
    int increment() default 1
    String metricPrefix()
}
```

And my Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class UnoMetricsAspect {
    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass())
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    @Before("@annotation( com.enterprise.annotation.UnoMetricsCounter)")
    void counterMetric(JoinPoint jp){
        String prefix = jp.getSignature().getMethod().getAnnotation(UnoMetricsCounter.class).metricPrefix()
        Long increment = (Long)jp.getSignature().getMethod().getAnnotation(UnoMetricsCounter.class).increment()

        log.info("IncrementCounterMetric has been called with prefix: "+prefix)
        MetricsUtils.incrementCounter(UnoMetricsUtils.addInfoToMetricName(UnoMetricsUtils."${prefix}", springSecurityService?.getCurrentUser()?.location?.name), UnoMetricsUtils.REGISTER_GRAPHITE_NAME,increment)
    }
...
}
```

I have another custom annotations with no aspect not working either.

I am not sure about what had happened because all the rest of not custom annotations works fine, I have found in google with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled the component scanner?

Comment: A quick test would be to annotation your Grails 3 `Application` class with `@ComponentScan`.